# How to check history of a particular software start and close event on windows7

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008, event-log

I have used event viewer to check system log in but how to check if I want to see if someone opened visual studio on system? I think its info should be in event viewer but I am not sure. I have checked Windows Logs then Application its showing of Skype update clearly but not about visual studio.

Comment: Windows does not log application usage like this.

Comment: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS it show the events

Comment: sql server events and user applications are two completely different things

Comment: But I tested when I opend visual studio it entered this event so Its my guess I am not sure still.